# How to deal with very big numbers producing NaN

Tags: r, function, calculation

I want to define very simple function following:

[image]

where:

[image]

**My work so far**

```
prob <- function(x, n) {
  quan <- qgamma(0.95, n, 1)
  temp <- quan / (x)^2
  first_term <- exp(-temp)
  second_term <- temp^(0:(n - 1)) / factorial(0:(n - 1))
  second_term <- sum(second_term)
  first_term * second_term
}
```

The problem here is that in the sum (second term) for big n we are dealing with very big numbers, so R treats those as infinity.

So for example:

```
prob(0.5, n = 1000)
[1] NaN
```

Because quantile for n = 1000 equals to  1052.577, in nominator we have to calculate  1052.577^999 and in denominator factorial of 999. R understands those two numbers as infinity:

```
> factorial(999)
[1] Inf
> 1052.577^999
[1] Inf
```

So when it tries to divide them `NaN` is produced. However the output of this function is always in interval (0, 1), since its a probability. Is there any possibility to calculate value of this function in this point?

Comment: One obvious option is to construct the individual elements of the summation on the log scale and then exponentiate before summing.

Comment: `Inf/Inf`
# [1] NaN

Comment: `Brobdingnag` package does what Limey suggests to deal with large numbers

Comment: I downloaded the package. unfortunately I obtain this result using it> `brob(1052.577^999 / factorial(999))
[1] +exp(NaN)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `prob` function is just the cumulative Poisson with `lambda = temp` and `k = n - 1`. Use `ppois`:

```
prob <- function(x, n) {
  return(ppois(n - 1, qgamma(0.95, n, 1)/x^2))
}

prob(0.5, n = 1000)
# [1] 0
```

`prob(0.5, n = 1000) = 0` because `n - 1 = 999` is so far from the mean (lambda = `qgamma(0.95, 1000, 1)/0.5^2 = 4210.308`).